# Realtime Message based WCF service performance with SQL Server backend

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, multithreading, wcf

I'm currently in the process of attempting to write a high performance WCF service. Throughput is a must. I'm aiming to do at least 500tps per second.

I've got a test harness set up on my machine and am looking for input and guidance to handle performance bottlenecks.

Essentially:

The message comes in in xml format

- I deserialize the message (should I do this in T-SQL or C#? C# seems faster but since I'm going to SQL Server in any case...)
- I store the message data in SQL Server
- I do some processing on the message in SQL Server
- I return the resulting xml out to the caller (again C# or T-SQL)

I did a rough test and seem to be getting around 200 tps with just a single table insert after shredding the xml and responding over nettcp

Through some investigation I have found a massive performance bottleneck in SQL Server (just with a simple table insert with a single column just storing the xml which is only 5 lines of text)

What can I do to decrease the cost of my T-SQL operations in my real time service, unfortunately the operations have to be blocking due to the flow of what happens.

IO seems to be a huge expense and I'm trying to maximise the performance of my solution.

WCF is configured to use per instance calls and has been tweaked. If I take out the SQL call I get roughly 1500tp/s! I am wondering what I can do to fix the IO bottleneck (I'm using SQL Server 2008)

Thank you for any input which you might have.

Comment: Ok, to get this straight: when you say deserialize do you mean you deserialize in an object instance in C#? Is there an XML Schema to which the XML messages conform?

Comment: Yes, or alternatively just strip the xml in Sql.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to see the SQLXML library. I have been using it a lot for the last year and it is really the fastest way to load an XML to a relational database. So, IMHO, the best way to do this is to load the XML to the database using SQLXML bulk load (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171806.aspx) and instead of shredding the XML in the database, you can tell SQLXML to generate for you a relational model i.e. the tables you need to store the XML data. Then you can use the tables to do your processing using set-based logic (this way you can actually optimize the queries) and then using "for xml" to recreate the XML.